# Rx: Should API calls be Singles or Observables of Started, Success, Error events?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

Should API requests be Single or rather Observable of Started, Success, Error events (with onError should never occur)?

Current state is IntentService with Started event posted by EventBus, synchronous api call, Success event or Error event.

The latter sounds ike a better fit, but then how would one do say saving to database after the api call? I would have to have if instanceof Success in doOnNext. Feels weird. How do you guys usually do this?

Comment: Why do you need the event bus? If you have Observables, they can hep with your control flow; if you network traffic tracking, you can do it via lower-level constructs (f.e. if you're using retrofit+okhttp for the network calls, you can add an okHttp interceptor that fires around your actual network call).

Comment: I dont need event bus with rx, events are just pojos, interceptor feels too low level as the event objects could contain data, if you understand what i mean

Comment: An event bus connects disparate pieces of your application in a way that when you generate an event you don't need to know a priori who is going to receive it and react to it. If you just need error processing, reactive streams are excellent because they leave up to you where this error handing happens. Thing is, do you need to be notified at every step in the http call process (you need to keep track of all the bytes/network operations), or are you concerned about the result that you'll get?

Comment: Yes I know. No I just need to notify the ui that made the request, about the state of the request (show progressbars, show actual data, show errors). Kind of like Jake Wharton here https://youtu.be/0IKHxjkgop4. The problem is that I would like to attach data to all these events, not just the success. For example, load more pagination. I need to attach page index so ui can decide to show big fullscreen progressbar (first page), or progressbar in the last item of adapter (2nd+ page)

Comment: I know I can just call handleRequestStarted() manually before subscribing to the request observable, however isnt the idea (as per Jake´s talk) to have the stream be a pipeline without sideeffects? So shouldnt the page index parameter inserted to the stream, bubble all the way to the end to the subscribers? (Now when I think about it, in other words, what I would need is to add more parameters to onStart, onNext, onError)

Comment: Extend the *payload* that you're sending - e.g. instead of just FooType, send an object that has Pagingation + FooType. Where does this pagination come from?

Comment: It comes from the UI, recyclerview with infinite scroll. The Activity keeps current page index in a member and increments it when recyclerview is near end of the list and starts the stream ... Yes, isnt that the Observable<RequestStateEvent> I said in the question? How else would I propagate pagination data to onError?